# Cast into a decimal with a specified amount of decimal places

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to cast a number into a decimal with a specified number of decimal places? I tried:

```
SELECT ...
       CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(15, @DecimalPlaces) AS NumericField,
       ...
```

But it didn't work.

---

**EDIT**: I made a mistake and wrote `NUMBER` instead of `NUMERIC`. But the question stands still: How do I cast to a `NUMERIC` with a specified number of decimal places?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be as DECIMAL not as NUMBER

Comment: @Conrad Frix: In SQL Server, `NUMBER` and `DECIMAL` are synonyms, AFAIK. In any case, the database I am working with has all its fixed-point decimal fields specified as `NUMBER`s.

Comment: @eduardo I knew about [numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=sql.90).aspx)(although I never used it) are you sure about NUMBER

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Oh, yes... It was `NUMERIC`. My bad.

Comment: @eduardo - It is `NUMERIC` that is the correct synonym but I don't think this is possible without dynamic SQL or some huge `CASE` expression which `casts` to the correct decimal places and then into `sql_variant`

Comment: @Martin: Oh, nevermind. This means I will have to do the cast in the application instead of the database.

Comment: Unless you want them cast to strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @decimal int=5
declare @decimalNum float =8931.0380106023125083

select ROUND(@decimalNum, @decimal,1)
```

For trailing zeros use this:

```
declare @decimal int=5
declare @decimalNum float =8931.12

select STR(@decimalNum, 25, @decimal)
```

Please note, the above select will return a varchar type, not decimal, numeric, float or any other types.

Comment: This won't preserve trailing zeroes. If you try `declare @decimalNum float =8931` and 5 `dp` it displays `8931` rather than `8931.00000`

Comment: oh i see what you're trying to do. You need a formatted string representation, not a decimal, cause 8931.00000 is not a decimal, it's integer.

Answer (score 5):

```html
declare @Value float = 123.4567, @RoundTo int = 2
select round(@Value * power(10, @RoundTo), 0) / power(10, @RoundTo)
```

Comment: This is precisely what I thought would be the most elegant solution and needs to be at the top (the current top answer results in a string, not a number, it's a recipe for trouble)

Comment: @Digs - this doesn't answer the question though. Rounding is easy - just use `ROUND(@Value,@RoundTo)` I'm unclear what the `power` is bringing to this. But that wasn't the question

Answer (score 2):

One way...

```
WITH T(NumericField, DecimalPlaces) AS
(
SELECT 1.234,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1.234,3 
)
SELECT CASE DecimalPlaces 
        WHEN 15 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 15))
        WHEN 14 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 14))
        WHEN 13 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 13))
        WHEN 12 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 12))
        WHEN 11 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 11))
        WHEN 10 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 10))
        WHEN 09 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 9))
        WHEN 08 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 8))
        WHEN 07 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 7))
        WHEN 06 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 6))
        WHEN 05 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 5))
        WHEN 04 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 4))
        WHEN 03 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 3))
        WHEN 02 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 2))
        WHEN 01 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 1))
        WHEN 00 THEN CAST(NumericField AS NUMERIC(30, 0))
        ELSE CAST(NULL AS SQL_VARIANT)
        END
FROM T
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to cast as decimal instead of a number..

cast(value  as decimal(10,2)) 10 is the total numbers including the decimals and 2 is the number of decimals

Comment: (BTW, is it actually Domínguez?) I want to be able to specify the amount of decimal places as a parameter.

Comment: Both numeric and decimal give the same value:   declare @Value2 float = 123.4567;
Select cast(@value2 as numeric(6,2))
Select cast(@value2 as decimal(6,2))

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this :
    DECLARE @quantityPrecision INT=5;
    set @quantityPrecision = yourvalue
    update tableA
    set quantity = round(quantity,@quantityPrecision)
    where XXX