# Declare VARCHAR(x) with x as a parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a very basic question about declaring some variables in TSQL.

When i declare a numeric variable in TSQL like this, everthing is ok:

```
DECLARE @Value AS NUMERIC(18,2) = 1.23
```

But what if i want the decimals to be set with a parameter?

```
DECLARE @NrOfDecimals AS INTEGER = 2
DECLARE @Value AS NUMERIC(18,@NrOfDecimals) = 1.23  
--This second line throws a compile error "Expecting  INTEGER"
```

So the second line throws a compile error "Expecting  INTEGER".

But isn't @NrOfDecimals an Integer? So why is the compiler complaining??

Am i missing something??

Comment: The compiler is complaining because it wants a *number*, not a variable. A lot of T-SQL has restrictions like this. Why do you want to vary the number of decimals? Do you do this in any other language?

Comment: Are you trying to round values in SQL? or why would you want to change the number of decimals like that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118325/cast-into-a-decimal-with-a-specified-amount-of-decimal-places

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , i want to do this because we have a table with a field of type VARCHAR, but in some cases, the value in this field is actualy a numeric (could be 5 or 3.1 of 34.87). I want to do some math with this varchar/numeric value, so need to convert it to a numeric with the right nr of decimals

Comment: @SanjeevRai Thanks for pointing me to this topic. Although i still don't exactly understand why this can't work, i guess i just have to live with it...

Comment: I would declare @Value with the highest amount of decimals available. Handling data is one issue, displaying data with a varying amount of decimals should not be handled here.

Answer (score 2):

You could dynamically create your queries and execute them.

This will work for the situation in your question:

```
DECLARE @NrOfDecimals AS INTEGER = 2
DECLARE @myCommand as NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @myCommand = 'DECLARE @value as numeric(18,' + CAST(@NrOfDecimals as VARCHAR) + ') = 1.23'
execute sp_executesql @myCommand
```

In order to do this for every situation, you should create a table with all queries you will have to run.

In order to create all of these queries you will have to use a cursor.

Documentation for cursors you can find here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx
- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Also, I have answered another question and gave an example with a cursor:

- [SQL Query to find a column name throughout the Database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17018402/1266737)

Comment: Declaring a variable inside a separated dynamic statement (with its own scope of course) is useless.